# stopped receiving email from our own server

Tags: email, email-server, spam, bulk

I have a website with a registration system, that sends new users a confirmation email after registering, and sends myself a `new user registered` email.

A few weeks back, I created a newsletter subscription system. While testing it, I sent around 50-70  emails over the course of a week using `php`'s `mail()` function, to various valid and

Suppose I have the domain `abc.com`, and I use an email system on my domain accessible at `mail.abc.com`.

The problem I'm having is:

1. Since last week, I've stopped getting emails from the registration module.
2. I don't receive newsletter subscription confirmation emails from my newsletter subscription system if I use an email from my domain, like `admin@abc.com`, but I do if I register with something else,  like from Gmail or Yahoo! mail, and so on.

So its clear that problem is only on my domain. Can anyone explain what's going on and what needs to be done to fix it?

I have checked if my domain is blacklisted, and it's not.

Comment: have you checked your mailer configuration?

Comment: Did your domain registration for `abc.com` expire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the logs, Luke. The truth lies in the log files. If you don't have log files for your mail system, then it is not a real mail system. If you don't have a real mail system, then establish one.

Comment: I check logs it says "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host." What confusing me is it sends emails to gmail, yahoo etc it fails only for the @abc.com

Comment: Firewall, DNS misconfiguration, network issues (routing, packet sizes, ...), receiving mail server hickups, ...